# React-Select bring cursor between inputs

Tags: javascript, react-select

I am using React-Select v2.4.4 multi-select feature. I am able to select multiple inputs and they are getting rendered absolutely correctly. But i am unable to click between inputs(place cursor between inputs).

By default, cursor remains at end of input like  in below example:
[image: cursor is at end of inputs] Now to remove all elements before 5, i need to remove all inputs individually by clicking on it's `x` mark.

I want to bring cursor between inputs(between 5 and 8) so that i can quickly remove all inputs before 5 with backspace.

I want to place cursor at position shown in below image:
[image]

Any idea on how to achieve this is highly appreciated.

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-vtgu7

Comment: No, you can't. The input you see is a ```div``` so you can move cursor on it.

Comment: @TienDuong They are array of divs that i get, but can't i place cursor between them?

Comment: You can only place cursor in ```input``` not in a ```div```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @NihalChandwani No. Tried but couldn't find anything useful